# SQL query did not return any values

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi i have the following table structure.

```
Professor (EMP ID,Name,Status,Salary,Age)
Course(Course ID,Course Name,Points)
Works(Course ID,EMP ID,Class ID)
```

I need to do the following.

Return List of Employees who have taken 2 different course M1 and M2  for the same class ‘class 10’

This is the query that i have written.

```
SELECT p.EmpID, p.Name, p.Status, p.Salary 
FROM professor p, course c, works w 
WHERE p.EmpID = w.EmpID
AND
w.CourseID = c.CourseID
AND
w.ClassID = 10
AND
c.CourseName IN ( SELECT CourseName FROM course WHERE CourseName = 'm1'
AND CourseName = 'm2')
```

But the query doesnot return any values even though there are data in the db.

Comment: is coursename nullable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is commonly called `Relational Division`

```
SELECT  a.EmpID, a.name
FROM    Professor a
        INNER JOIN Works b
            ON a.EmpID = b.EmpID AND b.ClassID = 10 
        INNER JOIN  Course c
            ON b.CourseID = c.CourseID
WHERE   c.CourseNAME IN ('M1', 'M2')
GROUP   BY a.EmpID, a.name
HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT c.CourseNAME) = 2
```

- [SQL of Relational Division](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)

Comment: i am getting this error when i execute your query   - Column 'EmpID' in on clause is ambiguous

Comment: oops my bad sorry for the typo, try again. `a.EmpID = EmpID` should be `a.EmpID = b.EmpID`

Answer (score 1):

The subquery

```
( SELECT CourseName FROM course WHERE CourseName = 'm1' AND CourseName = 'm2')
```

will return nothing. Look at the "AND"

Comment: `CourseName = 'm1' AND CourseName = 'm2'` will *ALWAYS* return **FALSE**

Comment: Exactly this is my point. Hence the IN ... will never find anything and hence the whole query will return nothing